# Sorting distinct results into different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have table that contains information on classes like CPR, First Aid, etc...I would like to sort and display this information into a table for each class type. So all of the CPR classes would be in a table then a new table for the first aid classes, etc...

The code below currently puts each class into it's own table...I need to group them together by className if possible.

Thanks in advance for any help.
Scott

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM providerClasses WHERE clientId = '$clientId' ORDER BY className");

$i = 0; // Start count for BG color
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 


echo "<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"2\" class=\"gridTable\" width=\"975\" style=\"margin-bottom:100px;\">";
echo "<tr class=\"gridHeader\">";  
echo "<td width=\"88\" class=\"grid-header-cell\">Date</td>"; 
echo "<td width=\"161\" class=\"grid-header-cell\">Time</td>";  
echo "<td width=\"143\" class=\"grid-header-cell\">Instructor</td>";
echo "<td width=\"179\" class=\"grid-header-cell\">Location</td>";
echo "<td width=\"8\" class=\"grid-header-cell\">Price</td>";
echo "<td width=\"210\" class=\"grid-header-cell\">Class Name</td>";
echo "</tr>";


   $className = "$row[className]";
   $date = "$row[date]";
   $time = "$row[time]";
   $instructor = "$row[instructor]";
   $location = "$row[location]";
   $price = "$row[price]"; 
   $comments = "$row[comments]";  
   $i++;


// Determine background color of row
if ( $i & 1 ) { $style = "GridRow-Even"; //even
} 
else { $style = "GridRow-Odd"; //odd
}

echo "<tr class=\"$style\">"; 
     echo "<td> $date</td>";
     echo "<td> $time</td>";
     echo "<td> $instructor</td>";
     echo "<td> $location</td>";
     echo "<td> $price</td>";
     echo "<td> $className</td>";
echo "</tr>";    

   } // end while

     echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Would this be a sql problem or do I need another while loop for the results? - Scott